# Calculate storage file volume by month

Tags: powershell

I need to trawl through a lot of daily automatically generated data going back a number of years, and show monthly totals of file size.

I can do this by file count no problem and it has shown pretty much what we expected, but how do I group by data volume?

My current solution is a PS one liner and gives what I need for the file count. I need the same for data volume but just cant get it right, nothing I try works.

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Data -recurse | Group {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM")} | Sort Name | Format-Table Name,Count -auto > filecount.txt
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'data volume'?

Comment: Do they take up 500kb or 1GB per month and so on.  total file size per month.  Total size per month.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the files to `Measure-Object -Sum` to get the total volume by measuring the `Length` property:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Data -recurse | Group {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM")} |ForEach-Object {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Month = $_.Name
        Volume = ($_.Group |Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also change the unit into MB/GB/TB with a small tweak, depending on the volume of files the makes reports easier to read when there's a large volume of files: `Volume = "{0:N2}" -f (($_.Group |Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum /1MB)`

Comment: Its spitting out the old 

Measure-Object : Property "Length" cannot be found in any object(s) input.

chestnut.  I was getting this earlier.  Tried rearanging it, no joy.

Comment: Actually is does seem to be working, just spits that out half-way through.  Just after doing November 2013.  Wonder if its because the next one - April 2014 is empty.